# multiple LIKE does not work in PDO (PHP)

Tags: php, pdo, sql-like

Hey I'm having this in my PDO function where I want to check 2 columns of my database with the same input ($string). This comes from my HTML search box. I want the results in one array. However with this code it only checks the `genre` column and not the `name` column. But it should check on both columns. Any help? Thanks.

```
public function search($string){
    $question = '%' . $string . '%';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` OR `genre` LIKE :q";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':q', $question);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = '%$data%';
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I get this error when I use this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` like :q OR `genre` LIKE :q";
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bad/bad/dao/ProductsDAO.php:32 Stack trace:
>   #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bad/bad/dao/ProductsDAO.php(32): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bad/bad/controller/ProductsController.php(24):
>   ProductsDAO->search('pokemon') #2 [internal function]:
>   ProductsController->index() #3
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bad/bad/controller/Controller.php(9):
>   call_user_func(Array) #4
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bad/bad/index.php(50): Controller->filter()
>   #5 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bad/bad/dao/ProductsDAO.php on line 32

Comment: Answer Edited, please check the changes. let me know if you have doubts or errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your query isn't passing values to the Where clause, only the column name. 
Also i edited the way that you are passing the parameters to the execution.

The error that you was experiencing is due to (extract of docs):

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement. You cannot bind multiple values to a single named parameter in, for example, the IN() clause of an SQL statement.

so I've edited the answer.

Try this:

Modify this lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` OR `genre` LIKE :q";
$stmt->bindValue(':q', $question);
$stmt->execute();
```

for this ones:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE :name OR `genre` LIKE :genre";
$params = array('name' => $question, 'genre' => $question); //or :name and :genre
$stmt->execute($params);
```

if you still getting errors, please take a look into the documentation it has a few examples in there. [PHP PDOStatement::execute Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: It's still not working, I still get that same error.

Comment: still not doing it :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function search($string){
    $question = "%".$string."%";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE :n OR `genre` LIKE :q";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':q', $question);
    $stmt->bindValue(':n', $question);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. You just saved my school project